# how to call php script with ajax that doesnt need a response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to implement a timer e.g. time spent online. This will be correct to the nearest minute. Every 60 seconds it will add +1 to the minutes column for the user in the db table.

```
var timer = 60000;
setInterval(function(){isOnline()},timer);
```

will call the isOnline() function and from this function i want to call the php script updateTime.php. This script does not return anything it simply updates the db +1. I have validation and stuff on this to stop cheating but on a basic level I don't know how to make an Ajax call that doesn't return something. I have found an ajax function that works onclick but i need this to be called by the setInterval and not to bother the user.

```
$(function isOnline() 
{
    $(#).load("updateTime.php?ID=<php echo $id;?>");
})
```

I was trying something like this but it isn't getting triggered. Anyone got any advice for this?

Comment: usually this is done with **one** ajax call in the document.unload event handler.

Comment: `$.post("updateTime.php?ID=<php echo $id;?>");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/):

```
setInterval(function(){
    $.get("updateTime.php", { ID: "<php echo $id;?>"} );
}, 60000);
```

Comment: damn that wasnt hard at all.. thanks dude. I said id give you the right answer since i like how you implemented it all into the 1 function. Thnaks

Answer (score 2):

simply use `$.post` :)

```
$(function isOnline() 
{
    $.post("updateTime.php?ID=<php echo $id;?>");
})
```